# Unable to Parse a SPARQL Result Set since a <literal> element has too many Attributes

Tags: xml, sparql, sesame, dotnetrdf, openrdf

I'm working with dotNetRDF and was trying to execute a SPARQL query

```
PREFIX rdfh: <http://lod2.eu/schemas/rdfh#>

SELECT * WHERE{ ?lo_orderdate <http://lod2.eu/schemas/rdfh#d_year> ?d_year .
FILTER(?d_year = 1993) }
```

but got this error when trying to execute it against Sesame:

```
Unable to Parse a SPARQL Result Set since a <literal> element has too many Attributes, only 1 of 'xml:lang' or 'datatype' may be specified!
StackTrace:
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlXmlParser.ParseValue(SparqlXmlParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlXmlParser.Parse(SparqlXmlParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlXmlParser.Load(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, TextReader input)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlXmlParser.Load(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, StreamReader input)
   at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, String sparqlQuery)
   at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(String sparqlQuery)
   at VDS.RDF.Query.RemoteQueryProcessor.ProcessQuery(SparqlQuery query)
```

The sample of the TTL file looks as follows:

```
@prefix xsd:  ... .
@prefix rdfh: ... .
@prefix rdfh-inst: ... . # cannot put real values - don't have enough reputation
rdfh-inst:date_19920101 a rdfh:date ;
rdfh:d_datekey 19920101 ;
rdfh:d_date "January 1, 1992" ;
rdfh:d_dayofweek "Thursday" ;
rdfh:d_month "January" ;
rdfh:d_year 1992 ;
rdfh:d_yearmonthnum 199201 ;
rdfh:d_yearmonth "Jan1992" ;
rdfh:d_daynuminweek 5 ;
rdfh:d_daynuminmonth 1 ;
rdfh:d_daynuminyear 1 ;
rdfh:d_monthnuminyear 1 ;
rdfh:d_weeknuminyear 1 ;
rdfh:d_sellingseason "Winter" ;
rdfh:d_lastdayinweekfl "0" ;
rdfh:d_lastdayinmonthfl "1" ;
rdfh:d_holidayfl "1" ;
rdfh:d_weekdayfl "1" .

rdfh-inst:date_19920102 a rdfh:date ;
rdfh:d_datekey 19920102 ;
rdfh:d_date "January 2, 1992" ;
rdfh:d_dayofweek "Friday" ;
rdfh:d_month "January" ;
rdfh:d_year 1992 ;
rdfh:d_yearmonthnum 199201 ;
rdfh:d_yearmonth "Jan1992" ;
rdfh:d_daynuminweek 6 ;
rdfh:d_daynuminmonth 2 ;
rdfh:d_daynuminyear 2 ;
rdfh:d_monthnuminyear 1 ;
rdfh:d_weeknuminyear 1 ;
rdfh:d_sellingseason "Winter" ;
rdfh:d_lastdayinweekfl "0" ;
rdfh:d_lastdayinmonthfl "1" ;
rdfh:d_holidayfl "0" ;
rdfh:d_weekdayfl "1" .
```

I guess i'm receiving this error because Sesame is returning two attributes and dotNetRDF expects only one

```
<head>
    <variable name='lo_orderdate'/>
    <variable name='d_year'/>
    <link href='info'/>
</head>
<results>
    <result>
        <binding name='d_year'>
            <literal q:qname='xsd:integer' datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'>1993</literal>
        </binding>
        <binding name='lo_orderdate'>
            <uri q:qname='rdfh-inst:date_19930101'>http://lod2.eu/schemas/rdfh-inst#date_19930101</uri>
        </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
        <binding name='d_year'>
            <literal q:qname='xsd:integer' datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'>1993</literal>
        </binding>
        <binding name='lo_orderdate'>
            <uri q:qname='rdfh-inst:date_19930102'>http://lod2.eu/schemas/rdfh-inst#date_19930102</uri>
        </binding>
    </result>
    </results>
```

I'm not receiving this error when using OpenVirtuoso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra attribute `q:qname` is a Sesame-specific extension of the standard format. It is a [configuration setting](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/resultio/BasicQueryWriterSettings.html) that is supported by Sesame's `SPARQLXMLWriter` but is not enabled by default.

It appears, however, that the Workbench client application enables this feature and adds these additional attributes when exporting query results. So I suspect that you are getting your query result by doing the query in the Workbench and then exporting the result to file. This is a bug in the Workbench application and has now been reported as such (see [SES-2059](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2059)).

A workaround is to instead query your Sesame server from a different tool, bypassing the Workbench's problem. You can use something like `curl`, or you can even do this from any web browser directly if you want.

For example, if your SPARQL query was this:

```
SELECT * WHERE {?S ?P ?O } LIMIT 100
```

and you have a Sesame server running on, for example, `localhost:8080`, and the repository you're querying is called `myRepository`, you can get the result from your Sesame server directly by entering this URL into your browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/myRepository?query=SELECT * WHERE {?S ?P ?O } LIMIT 100
```

Another workaround would be to appeal to the dotNetRDF developers to relax their parser's strictness a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, Jeen, indeed i used workbench. Since dotNetRDF is open source i changed it and recompiled and not receiving this error now. Your answer also helped me to resolve another issue... Thanks again.